# Check image validity in HTTP requests

Tags: java, image, http, connection

I am drawling images from Twitter. The images are reachable from URLs in the form:

```
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BzQXyBJIAAIU6D0.jpg
```

In order to retrieve the image, I apply the following code:

```
HttpURLConnection httpConnection =  (HttpURLConnection)  url.openConnection (); 
httpConnection.setRequestMethod ("GET"); 
httpConnection.connect(); 

int code = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

if (code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    int length;

    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, length);
    }

    is.close();
    os.close();

    httpConnection.disconnect();
}
```

However, it happens sometimes that images like these:

```
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/By_ui7QIgAE021Z.jpg
```

are somehow malformed, and although `code=200`, the code I posted here does not work, with the error:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/By_ui7QIgAE021Z.jpg
```

The exception is generated by the instruction `openStream()`.

How to prevent this from happening? How to check image validity?

Comment: Your code does not match the output. There is nothing in your code example capable of outputting 'Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment'.

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is that you're calling `getInputStream()` on your `url` object, instead of your `httpConnection` object.   Via your `httpConnection` object, you're already connected to the server and reading the response code.  That same object has an `openStream()` method, which I think you should be using.

At the very least, it looks like your code might have the side-effect of generating 2 connections per image instead of one.

Also, on your problematic URL, these are the headers I see coming back from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 06 Oct 2014 13:05:32 GMT
Server: tfe
cache-control: max-age=5, must-revalidate
content-security-policy-report-only: default-src 'none'; img-src https://abs.twimg.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com; script-src https://abs.twimg.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com about:; style-src https://abs.twimg.com 'unsafe-inline'; font-src https://abs.twimg.com https://twitter.com;connect-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; media-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; report-uri https://twitter.com/i/csp_report?a=ORTGK%3D%3D%3D&ro=false
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 4311
```

As a result, you should be checking for non HTTP 200 codes on the response...which you're doing, but you might want to double check this with curl or something else to verify that you don't have a proxy in the middle doing something odd.

Comment: Pardon me, but I did not understand what you are suggesting to check (instead of the error code).

Comment: The way you're checking the response code looks OK to me - but (a) you might have a proxy that's changing something, and (b) the openStream is on a separate connection than the one you're checking the status code on.

Comment: I have changed the code so that the `InputStream` is taken from the connection and not re-created from scratch, according to your suggestion (i.e., `httpConnection.getInputStream()`). Hope this fixes the thing.